# GAS - script to get all named ranges included protected ones - did not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function getNameProtectedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Requerimento');
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  Logger.log('protections.length: ' + protections.length);
  Logger.log('protections: ' + protections);
  Logger.log('typeof protections: ' + typeof protections);


  var rngList = protections.map(function(pro) {
    return pro.getRange().getA1Notation();
  });

  var rngList1 = protections.map(function(pro) {
   return pro.getRange().getRangeByName();
  });



  Logger.log('rngList: ' + rngList);
  Logger.log('rngListName: ' + rngList);

  for (var i=0; i<protections.length; i++) {

    // get the name of each named range
    var name = protections[i].getRangeName();
    Logger.log('Named range is: ' + name);
   }
}
```

```
Register:
[20-03-30 18:42:05:090 PDT] protections.length: 7
[20-03-30 18:42:05:097 PDT] protections: Protection,Protection,Protection,Protection,Protection,Protection,Protection
[20-03-30 18:42:05:099 PDT] typeof protections: object
[20-03-30 18:42:05:145 PDT] TypeError: pro.getRange(...).getRangeByName is not a function
    at [unknown function](Código:275:25)
    at getNameProtectedRanges(Código:274:30)
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question, but you can use the [`getNamedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getnamedranges) method to get all named ranges in a spreadsheet. Your use of `getRangeByName()` is incorrect.

Comment: Hello @jcom, please try to improve your question: it's not clear what is your problem and what have you tried to do so far. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on asking good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Diego, 
Sorry, I just edited the title, is it better?
I can't get the name of the named ranges

and not working: 

TypeError: pro.getRange(...).getRangeByName is not a function
    at [unknown function](Código:299:26)
    at getNameProtectedRanges(Código:298:30)

Comment: Test Spreadsheet: https://script.google.com/macros/d/1OYMUYYgL1Ni7TRc8SSmkmevUV5eBFerwtto2YY4tlN-W2dTc0-_iMOrO/edit?mid=ACjPJvFOOCw9RDbkI3G9nFG_LgJFVQ9Eglo8EERxI6i9Am6bU_f0veTALKqs0QWpVF8zAbtkydmXc8nsy4HoaXNsJQFonUlEQ7Qm4kwkes5wI5a0ccy11AZ8CGvtoUhv88qd3FpCZgZh_OU&uiv=2

Answer (score 1):

To get *all* named ranges, you can call [`getNamedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getnamedranges) and loop through that, calling [`getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getName()) on each range.

To list just protected named ranges, you have to [get the range protections](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getprotectionstype) in a spreadsheet and call [`getRangeName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#getrangename) on each protection. You have to keep Google's note about protected named ranges in mind, though:

> Note that scripts must explicitly call setRangeName(rangeName) to associate a protected range with a named range; calling Range.protect() to create a protection from a Range that happens to be a named range, without calling setRangeName(rangeName), is not sufficient to associate them. However, creating a protected range from a named range in the Google Sheets UI associates them automatically.

```
function listNamedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // List all named ranges
  var namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
  for  (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Range name is: " + namedRanges[i].getName());
  }

  // List protected range names, or null, if protected range is not named
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Protected range name is: " + protections[i].getRangeName());
  }
}
```

You were getting the error "TypeError: pro.getRange(...).getRangeByName is not a function", because you're calling `getRangeByName()` on a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. That method only exists on the [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object, however.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks agian.
I created a new spreasheet - shared below - and tried your code, but again I can't get the protected range's names
namedRanges.length: 1
Range name is: Sheet1ColARow2to10
protections.length: 2
Protected range name is: null
protections.length: 2
Protected range name is: null

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqOOf5oiPQIMm4k5RjOT16u2YKGdV6qltkwXUBLwp74/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Diego, I created the protected ranges thru the Sheets UI .
I can't get name calling getRangeName(); but I get calling getDescription().
What is the difference between "description" and "name" for a protected range?
I can't find specific fields in the UI for description and name!